# Setup fortran project in Xcode 10 with external build

Tags: xcode, makefile, build, fortran, xcode10

I would like to set up a fortran project in XCode 10. I need to use intel compilers which support XCode integration. I read that I need to use the external build system.
I've added a snippet in the Build Phases -> Run Script with

```
/path/install.sh
```

and I've removed the rest of the compilation as this should all be done within the script. If I try to build I get a console saying

```
bash: no job control in this shell
bash-3.2$
```

When I do this from command line I have an `install.sh` file which contains the calls to make.

I know that XCode does not have full support for Fortran, so I am not expecting code sensing or other fancy stuff. I would simply like my code to be built within the XCode IDE. The intel compilers are properly installed.

Comment: You could ask in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x or perhaps study the instructions in the Intel documentation for setting up projects in Xcode (https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference > Compiler Setup > Using Xcode)  I will note that Xcode builds don't understand module dependencies, which may be a barrier.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the suggestion. I found the the documentation I needed in the intel website. Still trying to figure out if I can setup a project with module dependencies. Some files seem to compile properly others not...

Comment: I don't think it works well with modules. Apple consistently refused Intel's requests to be able to hook into the build dependency system.